# Pushing file to a repository using from Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: git, azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, checkout

I have an azure devops pipeline that checks out two repositories with the following command

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: 'essentials'
      type : 'git'
      name : 'ic-essentials'
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
- checkout: 'essentials'
```

note `essentials` is a different repository to `self`.

later on it creates a file in the `essentials` repository with the following templated pipeline,

```
parameters:  
  - name: SolutionName
    type: string
    displayName: 'Name of the Solution to be saved'
  - name: Version
    type: string
    displayName: 'Semver version of the solution'
  - name: CoreRepository
    type: string
    displayName: 'Name of the core repository'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Setting git default'
  inputs:    
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |      
      git config --global user.email $(Git.UserEmail)
      git config --global user.name $(Git.UserName)     
           

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Create manifest'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        Write-Host "Logic for manifest creation is loaded"
        # A logic that creates a file in the following location
        # $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{parameters.CoreRepository}}/Manifest

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Committing files and pushing'
  inputs:    
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |      
      Set-Location -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{parameters.CoreRepository}}      
      git push --set-upstream origin main
      git add .
      git commit -m "Committing the manifest file"
      git push origin HEAD:main
```

i am getting the following error,

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProj/_git/MyRepo'
[detached HEAD f327404] Committing the manifest file
 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 Manifest/THEFILE.manifest.xml
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://MyOrg@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

i can confirm

- the repository exists. Also does the branch `main`
- the file is definitely getting created in the stipulated location.
- the agent `My Project Build Service (My Org)` as contributor access to the repository.
  [image]

I still think its to do with the access the agent has to the repository. am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you may test the sample below.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: essentials
    type: git
    name: ic-essentials
variables:
  essentialsRepoName: $[ resources.repositories.essentials.name ]
  Git.UserEmail: azxxxx@hotmail.com
  Git.UserName: $(Build.DefinitionName)

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: essentials
  persistCredentials: true #Use the System.AccessToken of the build service account to git push
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "1. Create a new file under $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(essentialsRepoName)/Manifest"
      New-Item -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(essentialsRepoName)/Manifest/NewManifest-$(Build.BuildId).md -ItemType File
      
      Write-Host "2. Configure git and push new manifest file to repo resource - $(essentialsRepoName)"
      git config --global user.email $(Git.UserEmail)
      git config --global user.name $(Git.UserName)

      Set-Location -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(essentialsRepoName)
      git checkout -b main
      git add .
      git commit -m "Committing the manifest file NewManifest-$(Build.BuildId).md"
      git push origin main
```

[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: your answer gave me the idea. i had `persistCredentials: true` set for the `self` repository but not for the `essentials` even if they are the same. it started to work after I had set it.

Comment: Good to know that helps. Thanks for your sharing and have a nice weekend. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small script to handle the credentials:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Committing files and pushing'
  inputs:    
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |      
      git config --global credential. Helper "!f() { echo \`"username=.`npassword=`${TOKEN}\`"; }; f"
      Set-Location -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{parameters.CoreRepository}}      
      git push --set-upstream origin main
      git add .
      git commit -m "Committing the manifest file"
      git push origin HEAD:main
  env:
    TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```